# The html created by google apps script is published in Google Docs and an error has occurred in From today

Tags: google-apps-script

Create the HTML in the google apps script project and add the [ Select "Deploy as a Web Application" and click on the Who has access to the app The html with the setting [anyone,even anonymous] has been published in [ An error has occurred in Google Docs] and it is no longer visible.

That has been confirmed since about 8:00 AM GMT on 7/7/2020.

The account that created the script or a completely unrelated Google account If you are logged in, it appears without problems, but if you are in secret mode or not logged in If you try to access the HTML in the state of [ An error has occurred in Google Docs] I am using the Japanese version.

The contents in [] may be different from the English version because I am using the Japanese version.

Is there a bug?
Or is this a spec change?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It seems that an error occurs when displaying the HTML after doGet(e) has been loaded I was able to display it in JSON format with no problem.

Comment: Some other people are experiencing [this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770318/google-script-app-fails-in-incognito-mode). Looks like an error with Drive. If you can still reproduce the issue, could you report it to [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=823909). Thanks!

Comment: The issue is now resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790735/512127

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script App Fails in Incognito Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770318/google-script-app-fails-in-incognito-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is the same as mine.
But that problem is solved it.
I guess that Google was down part of system.