# Google Apps Script doGet(e) createHtmlOutput returning broken Google Drive error page on Safari

Tags: google-apps-script, safari, http-status-code-500

I'm using the [GAS OAuth2 Library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) and on Safari (both OSX and web) when I try to call any doGet(e) with createHtmlOutput I get a broken G Drive page that looks like the below image.

```
function doGet(e){
          return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<b>Hello world!</b>") 
}
```

The weird thing is, I am sometimes able to get it to work, and other times I am not - this morning though, it is consistently returning the broken GDrive page which I believe is equivalent to html error code 500. Does anyone have experience resolving this? Thanks.

[image: [1]: https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62770318/

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: I've isolated the issue further, it has to do with whether a user is logged in, even if the script is published as anyone, even anonymous. I also just saw the other post from @TheMaster, thank you. Hopefully this is a temporary glitch.

Comment: Note there is a Google bug open on the issue tracker for this issue, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160665120

Comment: The issue has been resolved https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790735/512127